# Can I create an independent "usercontrol" in Android that contains UI and logic/code?

Tags: android, user-controls, components

UserControls - how do I do it in Android?

Some of the questions I have asked here on SO that has related to my struggle of creating "user controls" in Android, ie a reusable component that defines its layout as well as logic/code and can be placed in the app wherever I need it.

I want to be able to:

- Be able to instantiate the class so that I have an actual object of which I can access its properties, methods etc
- Place the UserControl inside another layout as defined in the layout-xml file
- Use the UserControl in an Dialog/AlertDialog

For example, I create an instace of MyUserControl. With that I can either place it in a PopupWindow and display it, OR use it in a Dialog/AlertDialog OR use it inside a layout somewhere. In all cases I have access to the object (myUserControl) so I can do stuff (myUserControl.SetObject(MyObject o) or something).

To put it shortly: .NET has the concept I am looking for with its modular "UserControl" that is an independent component that has both layout and code in it self (sure, the layout XML is a separate file, but that's OK). There are good reasons for this, as I really hate "code duplication". I want one piece of code/component that in can be used all over the place.

Is this doable?

Comment: That's a lot of text. Doing a short google search could have led you to the [Custom Components documentation](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/custom-components.html) which explains everything you ask.

Comment: Nops, I have read it through, I have googled for hours, I have read this forum over and over and I have not yet found a solution to the problem. The link you posted does not help as it does not answer my problem at all.

Comment: I suggest you try to do the things I mentioned in my post with the techniques the hardly even describe on that page. There is no info there to help out in this matter. I have trid Custom Components (extending different Layouts), extending Dialogs etc but none really match what I want.

Comment: I have built components like you describe here using the things described in that doc, so I already tried it. You might have misunderstand things or didn't read the site properly, but I'm confident this is exactly what you need.

Comment: Can you create one (1) "component" (extending a Layout) that I can use in a Dialog, in design-time layouts and at the same time be able to instanciate? I would love to know how...

Comment: ... and also has defined the UI and code inside that "component" so taht it is "self running" or whatever you wanna call it =)

Comment: Many of the inbuilt widgets are exactly like that. Here is the [NumberPicker source](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/ext/com.google.android/android/2.1_r2/com/android/internal/widget/NumberPicker.java). This could be written on your own instead of supplied with the framework. There is no difference in the used technique. It fits all your criteria of an independent, self-contained, reusable component that can be used everywhere (layouts, dialogs, ..). It has some inbuilt logic and also extends a layout class.

Comment: Today, there are "Fragments". When I asked the question, I dont think I knew about fragments or they didnt exist at that time. Fragments are the more "usercontrol"-like things in android (even though they are a lot messier to deal with than UserControls in .NET).

Answer (score 3):

1- make new xml file for your component. example:MyUserControl.xml
    - inside this file make your component as you want. example:linearLyout has two button.

2- make new class for your component and extends it from the root view of your xml file.         example:extends from LinearLayout.

3 - add this constructor to your class

```
 public ClassName(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
        LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) context
                .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        inflater.inflate(R.layout.yourXmlFile, this);

    }
    public ClassName(Context context) {
        super(context);
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
        LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) context
                .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        inflater.inflate(R.layout.yourXmlFile, this);
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

I know this is an old one, but this may help anyone looking for a XAMARIN solution / answer to this generic question -

https://matthewwaring.wordpress.com/2015/02/10/compound-controls-views-with-xamarin-android/

This post shows separation of code behind and AXML in a .net fashion and various ways to use it in your code, here is a snippet which uses codebehind, AXML for the actual user control and how to include the user control in the parent AXML.

XAML Code for "UserControl" -

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:id="@+id/compoundaxmlview_outerlayout">
    <TextView
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:text="TextView 1"
        android:id="@+id/compoundaxmlview_textview" />
    <Button
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:text="Button 1"
        android:id="@+id/compoundaxmlview_button" />
</LinearLayout>
```

Code behind to load this layout into the control and manipulate it -

```
namespace CompoundCustomControlView
{
    public class CompoundAXMLView : LinearLayout
    {

    // ...

    void Initialize ()
    {
        SetBackgroundColor (new Android.Graphics.Color (100, 100, 100));

        Inflate (Context, Resource.Layout.CompoundAXMLViewLayout, this);

        var b1 = FindViewById<Button> (Resource.Id.compoundaxmlview_button);
        var tv1 = FindViewById<TextView> (Resource.Id.compoundaxmlview_textview);

        tv1.Text = "Text2";
        b1.Text = "Button2";

        var layout = FindViewById<LinearLayout> (Resource.Id.compoundaxmlview_outerlayout);

        TextView tv = new TextView (Context);
        tv.Text = "Text2.1";
        Button b = new Button (Context);
        b.Text = "Button2.1";

        // Add inside our layout
        layout.AddView (tv);
        layout.AddView (b);
    }
}
```

}

And code to include it in parent view -

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent">
    <compoundcustomcontrolview.CompoundAXMLView
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="200dp"
        android:id="@+id/compound2" />
</LinearLayout>
```